# PHP SESSIONS Problem

Tags: php, session

I have two scripts but I can't make them work together.

1- A simply page views counter

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['views'])) 
$_SESSION['views']=$_SESSION['views']+1;
else
$_SESSION['views']=1; 
echo "Pageviews=". $_SESSION['views'];
?>
```

2 - A Random link from a list but without repeat the links

```
<?php
if (empty($_SESSION['links'])) {
    // first time visit, populate random links in session
    $links = array('http://some-site.com', 'http://some-other-site.com', 'http://example.com');
    shuffle($links);
    $_SESSION['links'] = $links;
}
$link = array_shift($_SESSION['links']);
$_SESSION['links'][] = $link;
?>
```

For some reason if I use one of them the other will stop to work, both had worked fine but I can't make them work together on the same site.

On the header I have `<?php session_start(); ?>` but I also moved the script to different parts of the site and I get always the same problem, one stop to work. I also had the `<?php session_start();?>` at the start of each piece of code but nothing seems to work.

At some point I manage to make both scripts work but the page views counter script was counting from 3 to 3, not from 1 to 1 - Note that the random link script have also 3 values on it; so my guess is that something is incompatible with both scripts

Any help and guide in how or where I need to place the code will be appreciated.

Thanks and sorry for my English
Daniel

Comment: how do you include each script in your pages, the key is certainly your include policy, if it counts from 3 to 3, means you've included it 3 times.

Comment: I had include the script on the index page/file (wordpress).But I also made some test by including the script on the header and on a extra file called on the body of each page like `<?php include('somefile.php');?>` On all these test Cokies form PC had been deleted and previous files had been deleted (repeated script)

Answer (score 0):

try is on the top of the code

just add "$_SESSION['views'] = 0;" to the top once when u run the main script i think it will work

```
$_SESSION['views'] = 0;

if (empty($_SESSION['links'])) {    
    // first time visit, populate random links in session    
    $links = array('http://some-site.com', 'http://some-other-site.com', 
'http://example.com');    
    shuffle($links);    
    $_SESSION['links'] = $links;    
}

$link = array_shift($_SESSION['links']);    
$_SESSION['links'][] = $link;    
echo "<pre>";    
print_r($_SESSION['links']);    
echo "</pre>"





if(isset($_SESSION['views']))     
$_SESSION['views']=$_SESSION['views']+1;    
else    
$_SESSION['views']=1; 

echo "Pageviews=". $_SESSION['views'];
```

Comment: If I paste this on the body the site crash (blank page).

Comment: Solved !!!

The solution provided before was close but not working, I just replace **`$_SESSION['views'] = 0;`** with **'$_SESSION['views']=$_SESSION['views']++;`** at the start, and all seems to be working fine.